# How to access the current value of dom element in react?

Tags: reactjs, dom, virtual, ref

iam using an external library which is updating the value of input element.So in my react code there is no value and onChange handler for that input element.Now the problem is that i want to access the latest value updated by ther external libarary to that element.Initially it is null.How to achieve that need help...

Comment: Using `ref`, you can directly access to an element in react

Comment: Need to see code...

Answer (score 1):

You can use state to keep track of your input value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ref` to access any element in the DOM directly.

Check the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for more details.